# Array de favoritos só é criado a partir do segundo terceiro item criado. (React JS)

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

```
const [favoritesList, setFavoritesList] = useState([]);
```

Acima tenho um useState criando um array de favoritos.

```
const handleAddFavorites = (disheId) => {
setFavoritesList((prevState) => [...prevState, disheId]);
```

};

Acima tenho uma função que decebe o id do prato em questão que está sendo exibido no componente card. onde ao clicar eu crio um array mantento os id anteriormente, inserindo um novo no final do array.

```
<button onClick={() => handleAddFavorites(dishe.id)}>
```

Aqui tenho o button que aciona a função..

Acontece que, tenho por exemplo 3 componentes cards renderizados.. cadea um está com id por exemplo: 67, 71 e 72..

Porém como na imagem abaixo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O array só é criado a partir do segundo item criado, e não inclui o primeiro item.

Sou novo em react..

Comment: Fala mano, tem esse código no github pra eu dar uma olhada??

Comment: https://github.com/viniseven/frontend_explorerfood segue o repositório

Comment: Está um pouco confuso, nesse seu print, há 4 arrays com apenas 1 item e 2 arrays de 2 itens. O que quer dizer com "O array só é criado a partir do segundo item criado, e não inclui o primeiro item."? Descreva o passo a passo que fez, o resultado atual e o desejado